# Check if a email exists with TELNET and PHP

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, telnet

I have seen some tutorials on stackoverflow about how to check if an email is existent or not and i don't quite understand how ...

**METHOD 1**

basically i have to run in cmd.exe the following commands

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
helo
mail from: <youremail@gmail.com>
rcpt to: <mailtocheck4@gmail.com>
```

And if the response is "OK" then we have a good email. I inserted all of this in a **.bat** file, and what the bat file does is just connect to the telnet and finishes ...

**METHOD 2**

use this
http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/#usage to connect to the telnet, but i don't know what password should i provide

```
<?php
require_once "PHPTelnet.php";

$telnet = new PHPTelnet();

// if the first argument to Connect is blank,
// PHPTelnet will connect to the local host via 127.0.0.1
$result = $telnet->Connect('mail.gmail.com','usr','password');

if ($result == 0) 
{
    $telnet->DoCommand('helo', $result);
    // NOTE: $result may contain newlines
    echo $result;

    $telnet->DoCommand('another command', $result);
    echo $result;

    // say Disconnect(0); to break the connection without explicitly logging out
    $telnet->Disconnect();
}
?>
```

Can you guys help me please?

Comment: I suspect this only works to check if a *gmail* account exists...

Comment: What do you want to check if it exists? Do you want to know if a particular email address is valid? Or to know if you can send via a particular account? Or something else? Either way I doubt either of your two approaches will work with Gmail, I'm pretty sure they require TLS for SMTP...

Comment: i have to know if some users provided me a real email address and not a fake one like fake243241addres423432243@yahoo.com witch is good from regex perspective, but ...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this yet? I am currently int he same situation as you are.

Answer (score -1):

the ok confirmation after the `rcpt to` does not validate that the email exists. It only indicates that the email you entered is in a valid email format. You will only know if the email is not existing if it does not bounced.

Comment: i have tried with several emails, and it seems that .bat really checks the integrity of the email

Comment: try using different smtp servers, I'm not sure if the basic telnet will be different based on the smtp server, but it is more probable that it will not. On exchange server, by default, it will only allow setting the `rcpt to` within the same domain and thus rejects if not. try using fictitious email address on `rcpt to` to check

Comment: even on the web interface of gmail, you are not restricted to use a fictitious recipient email. it will just bounce anyway but the protocol accepts it.